# jruby&rails 3.2 very slow compiling scss in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, performance, jruby, jrubyonrails, sass

I am using jruby-1.6.6 with rails 3.2 currently.

And I am using `gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.0.1'` to import twitter bootstrap as scss.

But in development mode, I start the app by `jruby -S rails s`, and every time I changes a little bit in the scss, and fires refresh page, it takes very long time to compile the application.css.scss, in which I import all other scss files.

the time it takes with `jruby-1.6.6` and `jruby-1.6.7`

```
Started GET "/playground/dashboard" for 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0 at 2012-02-29 12:30:18 +0800
Processing by PlaygroundController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"partial"=>"dashboard"}
  Rendered playground/_dashboard.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered playground/show.html.erb within layouts/application (2.0ms)
Compiled application.css  (11540ms)  (pid 5518)
Completed 200 OK in 11660ms (Views: 11660.0ms)
```

the time it takes with `MRI ruby-1.9.2-p290`

```
Started GET "/playground/dashboard" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-02-29 12:32:53 +0800
Processing by PlaygroundController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"partial"=>"dashboard"}
  Rendered playground/_dashboard.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered playground/show.html.erb within layouts/application (0.5ms)
Compiled application.css  (1283ms)  (pid 5674)
Completed 200 OK in 1323ms (Views: 1323.1ms)
```

Is there a way that I could tweak that?

Comment: Might be a bit late, but performance issues on production compilation are something I'm looking into. I haven't used the gem with JRuby, so I can't really comment on that.

Comment: thanks for your comment, but my problem is at development mode, when I need to change scss and refresh pages quite often to see the changes, and that incredibly slow with jruby do you know how to solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found out last evening that this is not a issue for jruby. But a issue when using jruby with bootstrap-sass.

If you are not this case, then jruby performs well even you have tons of scss being `@import`ed in the `application.css.scss`

Answer (score 1):

Go to `config/application.rb` and change the option:

```
config.assets.enabled = false
```

Comment: sorry, it's actually a particular problem when using bootstrap-sass. I am a spammer from some point..